# A floating window in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, overlay, android-jetpack

After searching all the guides and forums, I still haven't found the answer. Tried many times and now I'm writing here.

The most up-to-date code I could find on the Internet:

**1. Creating a class for the lifecycle:**

```
internal class MyLifecycleOwner : SavedStateRegistryOwner {

    private var mLifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)
    private var mSavedStateRegistryController: SavedStateRegistryController = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)

    val isInitialized: Boolean
        get() = true
    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry = mSavedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry
    override val lifecycle: Lifecycle = mLifecycleRegistry

    fun setCurrentState(state: Lifecycle.State) {
        mLifecycleRegistry.currentState = state
    }

    fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)
    }

    fun performRestore(savedState: Bundle?) {
        mSavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(savedState)
    }

    fun performSave(outBundle: Bundle) {
        mSavedStateRegistryController.performSave(outBundle)
    }
}
```

**2. In the service we try to create a floating window:**

```
val windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
params.apply {
    width = 500
    height = 500
    type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY
    gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
    flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
}

val composeView = ComposeView(this)
composeView.setContent {
    Text(text = "Hello", color = Color.Black, fontSize = 50.sp,
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize().background(Color.Green))
}

val lifecycleOwner = MyLifecycleOwner()
lifecycleOwner.performRestore(null)
lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
composeView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(lifecycleOwner)
composeView.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
composeView.setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(composeView.findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner())

val coroutineContext = AndroidUiDispatcher.CurrentThread
val runRecomposeScope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)
val recomposer = Recomposer(coroutineContext)
composeView.compositionContext = recomposer
runRecomposeScope.launch {
    recomposer.runRecomposeAndApplyChanges()
}

windowManager.addView(composeView, params)
```

But I got error: ***:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED***

**Full build output:**

> ! Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
> Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

I have tried many times to solve this problem, but all ended up with this error.

I really hope I can solve this problem and finally use floating windows along with jetpack compose. I wish someone would release a library to easily create floating windows, until there is an official solution. I hope the solution to this issue will help a lot of people.

**PS**: The error is caused if you add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0` to Gradle-defined dependencies. But I need this dependency, because the `internal class MyLifecycleOwner : SavedStateRegistryOwner` requires 2 arguments.

Comment: i think you should share your Gradle build config

Comment: This does not seem to be related to floating windows, but rather to your project setup, especially your Gradle-defined dependencies.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, that's right. I get it: if you add `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0'` to build.gradle (:app), it causes an error. But alas as I understood (I could be wrong ) I need this module. Otherwise `internal class MyLifecycleOwner : SavedStateRegistryOwner` will demand to add arguments. Full dependencies list `androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.3.3 androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.3.1 androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.3.3 androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.3 androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1 androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0`

Comment: @JamalD Hey, above, I described the error a little bit. If I need more, I'll add it to the main post.

Comment: It worked when I built it in a new project created by Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Path 1